# Fixing a closed question: Adaptive layouts in WPF

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, asking-questions, reopen-closed

The question [How can I create an adaptive layout in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013959/adaptive-layouts-in-wpf) was closed, because it is "vague, overly broad, and cannot be reasonably answered".

As you can see, I have a serious problem with WPF and I need to solve it. How to formulate the question and what information to add to make it good enough for Stack Overflow?

Do I need to show exact layouts and conditions for them? The problem is, there may be multiple approaches, and restricting to some exact layout examples could limit answers and I'd like to avoid that. For example, if I receive a comment, "You can't do that with StackPanel, but can do it with Grid", I'd effectively be forced to create yet another question so that the person could answer. It seems counterproductive to me.

Comment: I think in some sense you've answered your own question. `Do I need to show exact layouts and conditions for them? The problem is, there may be multiple approaches, and restricting to some exact layout examples could limit answers and I'd like to avoid that. ` - it may well be different approaches are better, but SO is more for I've tried this approach and it fails (here's the code - can someone help me to understand why) - not "what are my approaches" - maybe programmers (or potentially more specific forum) would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way WPF works, I think this question is fine for SO and have voted to reopen it. There is a reasonable and easy answer to the question based on the technology it uses.

The best way is to use `DataTriggers` on the parent element's `ActualHeight` or `ActualWidth` properties that sets child properties such as `Grid.Row` / `Grid.Column`, `StackPanel.Orientation`, or `DockPanel.Dock` to position items based on the size of the parent element.

Another method I've used in the past is to hook into the `Loaded` and `SizeChanged` event of the parent, and alter the visibility (or other properties) of the child objects based on if they're completely or partially visible.

But I'm getting off track here.

I've made a fairly significant edit to your question in an attempt to get it reopened.

Originally, it appeared at first glance to be an extremely broad question, and that image wasn't helped by having multiple example scenarios, none of which were actual code you appear to be using.

I've edited it to remove much of the extra text, and reduced it down to just one of your example scenarios that seems to adequately describe your situation.

It should be answerable in its current form, and I've voted to reopen it. If its not reopened in a few days and the votes start to expire, you can flag it for a moderator and explain it's been significantly edited, and ask for it to be reopened.

And if it does get reopened, I'll see about writing a full answer about how easy it is to do fluid layouts in WPF.

Comment: This is the solution I've thought about, but I don't particularly like it, because the code will quickly become unreadable. Grid layouts aren't very readable to start with, but with multiple layouts stuffed into them, with setters adjusting not only properties of controls, but properties of grid's columns and rows, I'm afraid the code will become incomprehensible. Ribbon controls, for example use "placeholders" approach http://pastebin.com/g7tehxhZ . I hoped there's a more generic way.

Comment: @Athari You can replace entire `Templates` in a `DataTrigger` too, which is a much simpler way of rearranging complex views. Usually I use `DataTemplates`, then set a `ContentControl.ContentTemplate` property based on a `DataTrigger`, although depending of the nature of the data I'm working with, I could also do something like an `ItemsPanelTemplate` and an `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel`

Comment: I've never thought of completely replacing templates using triggers. Sounds promising! Won't be as fast as just rearranging, but with ribbons and other complex controls resizing is relatively slow anyway.

Comment: I reopened the question with your edits, Rachel. It sounds like you might also have an answer in mind to post there, so feel free. I also noodled on migrating to Programmers, but it looks like it may be a bit too code-focused for that (although the mods weren't necessarily opposed when I asked for a sanity check). Still, the question's good on SO as is, and is now reopened. (cc @Athari)